# How to declare a Kotlin function with return type 'void' for a java caller?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a library that is completely written in Kotlin including its public API. Now a user of the library uses Java, the problem here is that Kotlin functions with return type `Unit` are not compiled to return type `void`. The effect is that the Java side has always to return Unit.INSTANCE for methods that are effectivly void. Can this be avoided somehow?

Example:

*Kotlin interface*

```
interface Foo{
  fun bar()
}
```

*Java implementation*

```
class FooImpl implements Foo{
   // should be public void bar()
   public Unit bar(){  
      return Unit.INSTANCE 
      // ^^ implementations should not be forced to return anything 
   }
}
```

Is it possible to declare the Kotlin function differently so the compiler generates a `void` or `Void` method?

Comment: change to public void bar() {} and it just work

Comment: Odd, their documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) suggests that it should be generated as void.

Comment: related discussion: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-interop-unit-closures-required-to-return-kotlin-unit/1842/13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `Void` and `void` work, you just need to skip that `Unit`...

Kotlin interface:

```
interface Demo {
  fun demoingVoid() : Void?
  fun demoingvoid()
}
```

Java class implementing that interface:

```
class DemoClass implements Demo {

    @Override
    public Void demoingVoid() {
        return null; // but if I got you correctly you rather want to omit such return values... so lookup the next instead...
    }

    @Override
    public void demoingvoid() { // no Unit required...

    }
}
```

Note that while [Kotlins reference guide 'Calling Kotlin from Java'](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) does not really mention it, the [`Unit` documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html#unit) does:

> This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.

And as we know, the following two are equivalent:

```
fun demo() : Unit { }
fun demo() { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe you have an idea for this case too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653202/how-to-declare-a-kotlin-lambda-with-return-type-void-for-a-java-caller

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple variant on this using a java interface.

--- In ACallback.java --

```
public interface ACallback<T> {
     void invoke( T data );
}
```

-- In a Kotlin file

```
fun dostuff( arg: String , callback: ACallback<String> ) { 
   stuff();
   callback(arg) ; // yes 'invoke' from java 
}
```

--- In java ----

```
  doStuff( "stuff" , ( String arg) -> voidReturningFunction( arg ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?):Void{
    for (i in 0 until 10) {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    return null as Void;

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion