# How to declare a Kotlin Lambda with return type 'void' for a java caller?

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I have a library that is completely written in Kotlin including its public API. Now a user of the library uses Java, the problem here is that Kotlin Lambdas with return type `Unit` are not compiled to return type `void`. The effect is that the Java side has always to return `Unit.INSTANCE` for methods that are effectivly `void`. Can this be avoided somehow?

Example:

*Kotlin Lambda*

```
interface Foo{
  fun bar(x:(String)->Unit)
}
```

*Java call*

```
public void call(){
   foo.bar(this::processString)
}

//the return type should rather be void instead of Unit
public Unit processString(String s){  
    return Unit.INSTANCE 
    // ^^ implementations should not be forced to return anything 
 }
```

Is it possible to declare the Kotlin Lambda differently so the compiler generates a `void` return type?

see also [How to declare a Kotlin function with return type 'void' for a java caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652393/how-to-declare-a-kotlin-function-with-return-type-void-for-a-java-caller)

Comment: This appears to be a known limitation of the Kotlin compiler since at least 2016 and as of 2020 there is no solution https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12455

Comment: And also here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21018

Comment: today I would rather go the opposite way and use the Java functional interfaces instead... Kotlin (and Java of course ;-)) handle them really well... alternative could be the Kotlin functional interfaces instead... but why reinvent all the interfaces? Probably depends on which platform you target mainly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Java interop is of topmost priority I would either just use the Java functional interfaces directly (i.e. `Consumer`, `Supplier`, etc.) or create custom [Kotlin functional interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) for now. Meanwhile Kotlin handles functional interfaces better...

Java variant:

```
interface Foo{
  fun bar(x : java.util.function.Consumer<String>)
}
// calling this from Kotlin today looks the same as if we used (String) -> Unit:
foo.bar { println(it) }
```

Kotlin variant with custom `Consumer`:

```
fun interface MyConsumer<T> { // just a demo... probably depends on your needs
   fun accept(t : T)
   // other functions?
}
```

Usage is similar as above. Maybe there is even an easier way today to handle something like `(String) -> Unit` as `Consumer<String>` but then I do not know it yet (or didn't feel the need to research for it yet ;-)). Compiler annotations as Ilya mentioned in the comments may be a way to solve this issue ~centrally.

In Dec 2018 I wrote: I do not have a real answer to this, but I will share, what I did in such a situation where I needed to access such Kotlin code from Java (or what has come to my mind).

Basically it depends which side you really want to touch/enhance just to get what you require.

Enhancing the Kotlin code to support the Java equivalents:

```
interface Foo {
  fun bar(x : (String) -> Unit)

  /* the following is only here for Java */
  @JvmDefault // this requires that you add -Xjvm-default=enable to your compiler flags!
  fun bar(x:Consumer<String>) = bar(x::accept)
}
```

This has some drawbacks: the `Consumer`-method is visible from Kotlin as well and is therefore also callable from there. Needless to say, that you need to duplicate all the functions in the interfaces and therefore your whole Kotlin-interfaces just get more bloated. But: it works from both sides the way you would expect. Java calls the `Consumer`-variant, Kotlin calls the `(String) -> Unit`-variant... hopefully ;-) actually just demoing some calls:

```
// from Java:
..bar(s -> { System.out.println(s); })
// however, method references might not work that easily or not without a workaround...
..bar((Consumer<String>) System.out::println); // not nice... @JvmName("kotlinsBar") to the rescue? well... that will just get more and more ugly ;-)

// from Kotlin:
..bar(Consumer(::println)) // or: ..bar(Consumer { println(it) })
..bar(::println)           // or: ..bar { println(it) } // whatever you prefer...
```

That having said, another variant is to add helper methods that actually help calling the Kotlin functions easier from Java, e.g. something as follows:

```
fun <T> `$`(consumer: Consumer<T>): (T) -> Unit = consumer::accept
```

Which will probably never be called from Kotlin (as writing the backticks combined with the $ is already cumbersome enough) or if you do not want to bloat your Kotlin code just add such a method to Java, where however it doesn't look that slim:

```
static <T> Function1<T, Unit> $(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        consumer.accept(t);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    };
}
```

Calls to those methods both look the same:

```
..bar($(s -> /* do something with s */)) // where bar(x : (String) -> Unit)
```

For the things I needed to solve I just returned `Unit.INSTANCE` or `null`, but if I had more methods to call I would probably have chosen the second (`$(...)`) approach. In the best case I only need to supply (generate? ;-)) equivalents once and use them in several projects whereas supplying `default` variants in the interfaces just for Java will probably require way more work and may even confuse some people...

Finally: no... I don't know of any option that allows you to have something like `void`-functional interfaces (/consumers) out of the `Unit`-returning functional interfaces of Kotlin.

Comment: Do you think it will be possible to remove some of this boiler code with compiler annotation?

Comment: hmmm... in the last 2 years lots of things have changed... today I would probably rather suggest to just use the Java `Consumer` instead... in Kotlin there is no need to write any boilerplate code anymore for Java functional interfaces. Other approach would be to use own Kotlin functional interfaces instead (`fun interface`). Did not experiment with compiler annotations yet, so can't really tell... sounds like there should be lots of things possible ;-) but if not really required, why even trying ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's no need to add the `$` symbol in Roland's answer.
You can directly achieve good coding experience in both kotlin and in java with only one method name.

Here's what you need to do (actually it's the same as Roland's answer but with my example code for you to refer to):

1. define an interface for java to use

```kotlin
interface `Consumer$`<T> : Function1<T, Unit> {
    fun accept(t: T)

    @JvmDefault
    override fun invoke(t: T) {
        accept(t)
    }
}
// this interface is a FunctionalInterface
// the `$` prevents importing collision with java.util.functional.Consumer
```

2. in your class/interface, add a function for java to call

```kotlin
class Foo {
    fun bar(f: (String) -> Unit) {}
    fun bar(f: `Consumer$`<String>) {
        bar(f as (String)->Unit)
                      // because that the `Consumer$` extends Function1
                      // it can be directly passed as a kotlin function
    }
}
```

3. in kotlin code, you may write

```kotlin
foo.bar { it.xxx }
```

4. in java code, you may write

```java
foo.bar(it -> it.xxx)
// as well as
foo.bar(System.out::println)
```

The javac knows that the return type of the referencing method is not `Unit`, so it will call the `Consumer$` method.
The kotlin compiler will not check the inheritance of `FunctionX`, so it will call the `(String)->Unit` method.